# Regex to match city names from text with numbers

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with the names of a cities and the numbers of people living in them. I need to match only names of cities using Regex

```
city = "New York - 8 468 000 Los Angeles - 3 849 000 Berlin - 3 645 000"
```

tried this

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

but it returns "None"

Comment: There is no name at [`$` the end of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Just drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all cities as a single string you can use `[a-zA-Z]+` to disregard all numbers and return a single string:

```
cities = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", city))
```

Returning:

```
'New York Los Angeles Berlin'
```

Otherwise if you want them separated, I would split by `-` first and then return using the same method as above in a list-comprehension way:

```
cities = [" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",x)) for x in city.split('-')[:-1]
```

Returning:

```
['New York','Los Angeles','Berlin']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+ ?[a-zA-Z]+(?= *-)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3D3lMm/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
([^-]+?)\s*-\s*([\d\s]+)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/0LCK0q/1)

---

```py
import re

city = "New York - 8 468 000 Los Angeles - 3 849 000 Berlin - 3 645 000"

pat = re.compile(r"([^-]+?)\s*-\s*([\d\s]+)")

for c, n in pat.findall(city):
    print(c, int(n.replace(" ", "")))
```

Prints:

```
New York 8468000
Los Angeles 3849000
Berlin 3645000
```

---

EDIT: If you don't need numbers:

```py
import re

city = "New York - 8 468 000 Los Angeles - 3 849 000 Berlin - 3 645 000"

pat = re.compile(r"([^-]+?)\s*-\s*[\d\s]+")

for c in pat.findall(city):
    print(c)
```

Prints:

```
New York
Los Angeles
Berlin
```

Comment: but i dont need numbers in match